# NANT modify assembly version for C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ant, nant

Below is a snippet of my NANT scripts that read the Assemblyversion from one of my C# project and increase it automatically.

```
<target name="CheckAssembly">
    <echo message="Check Assembly File version..." />
    <property name="file.contents" value="" />
    <loadfile property="file.contents" file="${properties.path}\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <regex pattern="(AssemblyVersionAttribute|AssemblyVersion)\(\x22(?'major'\d+).(?'minor'\d+).(?'build'\d+).(?'revision'\d+)\x22\)" input="${file.contents}" />
    <property name="application.AssemblyInfo.dir" value="${properties.path}" />
    <property name="AssemblyVersion" value="${major}.${minor}.${build}.${int::parse(revision)}" />

    <if test="${int::parse(updates.count)&gt;1}">
        <property name="AssemblyVersion" value="${major}.${minor}.${build}.${int::parse(revision) +1}" />
        <call target="UpdateAssembly" />
    </if>

</target>

<target name="UpdateAssembly" description="generates the version number">
    <echo message="Setting the build version to ${AssemblyVersion}..." />
    <attrib file="${application.AssemblyInfo.dir}\AssemblyInfo.cs" readonly="false" />
    <asminfo output="${application.AssemblyInfo.dir}\AssemblyInfo.cs" language="CSharp">
        <imports>
            <import namespace="System.Runtime.CompilerServices" />
            <import namespace="System.Reflection" />
            <import namespace="System.Runtime.InteropServices" />
        </imports>
        <attributes>
            <attribute type="AssemblyTitleAttribute" value="${appName}" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyDescriptionAttribute" value="" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyConfigurationAttribute" value="" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyCompanyAttribute" value="Company Name" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyProductAttribute" value="" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyCopyrightAttribute" value="Copyright ©  2010-2013" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyTrademarkAttribute" value="" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyCultureAttribute" value="" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyVersionAttribute" value="${AssemblyVersion}" />
            <attribute type="AssemblyFileVersionAttribute" value="${AssemblyVersion}" />
        </attributes>
    </asminfo>
    <attrib file="${application.AssemblyInfo.dir}\AssemblyInfo.cs" readonly="true" />
</target>
```

Now i am facing my next challenge.  I have a C++ project that compiles fine using NANT but I want to update the assembly version similar to what you see above.  In this C++ project I have my ProductVersion saved in the resource file (.rc).

Do you know if NANT has any functions/tag that assist in changing this?  If not do you have any idea of how I should approach this? I already thought about read file content and use regex to do this.

Comment: Did you ever found an answer for this ? @Fylix

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question but I have been working on the same problem today. I solved it like this using ANT (please excuse my regex :/ ). I am assuming that Nant will function in a very similar manner to plain ANT.

```
<echo message="Modifying VersionResource.rc" />
<replaceregexp byline="true" flags="g" encoding="UTF-16LE" >
    <regexp pattern="[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+" />
    <substitution expression="${adapter_resource}" />
    <fileset dir="${my.dir}">
        <include name="VersionResource.rc" />
  </fileset>
</replaceregexp>

<echo message="Modifying VersionResource.rc again..." />
<replaceregexp byline="true" flags="g" encoding="UTF-16LE" >
    <regexp pattern="&quot;(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}&quot;" />
    <substitution expression="&quot;${adapter_versions}&quot;" />
    <fileset dir="${my.dir}">
        <include name="VersionResource.rc" />
    </fileset>
</replaceregexp>
```

${adapter_versions} is set on the command line when calling the build process.